# Is there a way to create a hard connection from my PC to a laptop to install an OS on said laptop?

Tags: linux, boot, operating-systems

Im looking to switch my Fedora Linux laptop over to Ubuntu, and I dont have a USB to do the switch. I was wondering if I could create a hard connection between my Windows 10 PC and my laptop to do a file transfer.

Comment: Fairly easy to do a SSH connection and then do a rsync/scp. The hard part is reinstalling an OS on the disk using data that sits on that same disk. Unless you can set up your Windows PC to act as a LAN bBoot server (and there is a way to set up a Linux distro to install that way).

Comment: Can you remove the hdd fron the PC and put it in the laptop for the initial install. Linux is fairly forgiving of hardware mismatches/changes.